# Archimesh cabinet deformation

Tags: archimesh-add-on, surface-deform

[image]

How can I deform of change the shape of the whole archimech cabinet just to make it like sideways from the corner of the cabinet on the right to the edge of the door on the left i would like it to make it from square to trapezoid?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: I was just on my phone looking for help so i took a photo from my phone because i was using it to look up answers if i was on pc i would take a screenshot but i wasn't and i don't see how would a screenshot be more helpfull for my question which is how to make a cabinet trapezoid...